# Plot a 2D image in 3D space

Tags: python, opencv, matplotlib, plot

I want to place a 2D image like this one
\newline
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b79yW.png)

into a 3D space, such that the image is displayed at the Z = -10 and z = 10.

My current output looks like this.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m4p6q.png)

The problem is that the image is distorted and rotated to the right bij 90 degrees. The pixel height and width seem to match those of the original picture but clearly the image itself does not.

I have found some similar problems online with code, but those do not seem to work for me. (The code I used is a mix of code I found online and to be honest I don't understand each step)

The code I used is the following:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cv2

# Read the image with Opencv
img = cv2.imread('input_image')
# Change the color from BGR to RGB
img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)

# Orgird to store data
x, y = np.ogrid[0:img.shape[0], 0:img.shape[1]]
# In Python3 matplotlib assumes rgbdata in range 0.0 to 1.0
img = img.astype('float32')/255
fig = plt.Figure()
# gca do not work thus use figure objects inbuilt function.
ax = fig.add_subplot(projection='3d')

# minus 50 to place the image in the middle
ax.plot_surface(x-50, y-50, np.atleast_2d(0)-10, rstride=10, cstride=10, facecolors=img, label="TEST")
ax.plot_surface(x-50, y-50, np.atleast_2d(0)+10, rstride=10, cstride=10, facecolors=img, label="NO")

ax.set_xlabel('X')
ax.set_ylabel('Y')
ax.set_zlabel('Z')

fig.savefig('output_image')
```